# KivyLauncher: Incorret imaging on phone screen

Tags: python, kivy

I want to draw image (*.png file) at FlayoutBox, on pc is result OK, after using KivyLauncher is on phone screen only white square. I tested two variants for drawing (*draw_img_cnv* and *draw_img_wdg*), but both results are bad.
Cann you explain me:

- why is result white square on phone screen,
- why *draw_img_wdg* isn't centered on pc,
- how is diferent between both solutions?

Thank You!

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle, Ellipse
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.image import Image

import math

class Screen(FloatLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Screen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.li_item = []
        return

    def draw_img_cnv(self):
        size_img = (498, 498)
        pos_img = (self.center[0] -size_img[0]/2.0, self.center[1] -size_img[1]/2.0)

        with self.canvas:

            Color(0, 1, 0, 1)
            self.rect1 = Rectangle(size=self.size, pos=self.pos)
            self. rose = Image(source="rose.png",pos=pos_img,size=size_img )


    def draw_img_wdg(self):
        size_img = (498, 498)
        pos_img = (self.center[0] -size_img[0]/2.0, self.center[1] -size_img[1]/2.0)

        with self.canvas:

            Color(0, 1, 0, 1)
            self.rect1 = Rectangle(size=self.size, pos=self.pos)
        self. rose = Image(source="rose.png",pos=pos_img,size=size_img )
        self.add_widget(self.rose)
        return

class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.pos_sun = None
        root = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical')
        self.screen = Screen()
        button = Button(text = 'Press',size_hint=(1, None), height=50)

        root.add_widget(self.screen)
        root.add_widget(button)
        self.screen.draw_img_wdg()
        self.screen.bind(size=self._update_rect, pos=self._update_rect)
        return root

    def _update_rect(self, instance, value):
        self.screen.rect1.pos = instance.pos
        self.screen.rect1.size = instance.size
        self.screen.rose. pos = (instance.center[0] -498/2.0, \
                              instance.center[1] -498/2.0)
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Comment: The white square usually means that the specified image file cannot be found.

Comment: You are calling the `draw_img_wdg()` method in the `build()` method of the `MainApp`. At that point, the `pos` and `size` of the `Screen` will be the defaults (`pos` is `(0,0)` and `size` is `(100,100)`). So the `pos` of your rose `Image` will be calculated based on those values.

Comment: Oh yes, directory was without png file. Now is all OK, include positioning. Right coordinates are used by function _update_rect()